# RegEx: Matching HTML tags and text in a string of HTML

Tags: javascript, regex

I have written a regular expression which matches all `header` HTML elements, including their text. The present regular expression I am using is: `/<(h[1-6])[^>]*>(.*?)<\/\1>/gi`.

I want to match all **headings and text** until `testing-options` appears in the string below:

`<h1>jfhfnjkgf</h1><h2>fegsg</h2><h2>fwegrweghrw</h2><h4>sfadfsaf</h4><h4>ukfdsnsjkfsd</h4><ac:structured-macro ac:name="testing-options" ac:schema-version="1" data-layout="default" ac:local-id="8bbfe293-eeb9-4785-9873-9fb9b218692b" ac:macro-id="bed737bbfaaf5f1df5f68a0ecc0bc6a7"><ac:parameter ac:name="enable-testing">disable</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro><h3>bkbkvwv</h3><h4>vbdkhvbkwv</h4><h3>v n vw bv</h3><p />`

The final regex provided should match *every heading and text until* `testing options` appears in the string above. In this case, the match should be: `<h1>jfhfnjkgf</h1><h2>fegsg</h2><h2>fwegrweghrw</h2><h4>sfadfsaf</h4><h4>ukfdsnsjkfsd</h4>`.

Comment: "*until the string 'testing-options'*" - I do not see  'testing-options' at all.

Comment: In the provided text you can check

Comment: You can simply add a look ahead: `/<(h[1-6])[^>]*>(.*?)<\/\1>(?=.*testing-options)/gi`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following Regex without `global flag`

```
(<h[1-6]>\w+<\/h[1-6]>)*
```

Comment: Thanks. But it is not matching with the text before 'testing-options'
<h1>jfhfnjkgf</h1><h2>fegsg</h2><h2>fwegrweghrw</h2><h4>sfadfsaf</h4><h4>ukfdsnsjkfsd</h4>